# How can I access a service without bind to it?

Tags: android, service

I finished my android application, a mp3 player, but now I have some problems that I'm not sure if I am right or not.

To be more simple, I will just talk about the main problem.

I have 2 activities ( Program ( main act) and effect (for equalizer, bass booster)).

I have a service, name ServicePlayer, for playing music ( using Mediaplayer)

Now, I launch the app.

1. Program activity is launched, in this activity, I start the service and bind it to control music.
2. I launch the effect activity ( just press a button on Program act), in this activity, i do not bind to service that created before. I just use:

   ServicePlayer mSer = new ServicePlayer();*
   Note: I dont define any constructor in ServicePlayer class, just use default constructor ( so, there is no variable that is initialized when created a new servicelayer object).

then I use:

```
mSer.stop()// method to stop music in serviceplayer ( just call mediaplayer object to stop)
```

I'm wandering:

1. Why the method above can work while the effect activity does not bind to it?.
2. Does the line of code (*) create a new object of serviceplayer?. If yes, so there are 2 serviceplayer objects that can play music?. If no, so there is only 1 object of serviceplayer created at the first time and then, in the next callback, no new service created, just use created service before?
3. How can I access data of serviceplayer class without bind to it?. Actually, I can do that, but i dont know why because there is no variable of serviceplayer initialized (please see the line (*) above.

Thank you so much.

UPDATE ANSWER, thank Snicolas for help:

1. Because the method stop() will stop a static object mediaplayer. (Note: static member). If its not a static member, an NullPointerException would be what you receive.
2. Yes, Its create a new object, but not a new service. Only 1 and 1 service (of course, same service) can launch, when a service started, the next startService or bindService method callback will not create a new service. Just use old service.
3. Primitive variable, even String, enum type can access normally, but that is not data from service launched before, that is data from new object you create. For object type, if you dont initialze in constructor, an NullPointerException would be occured. However, you can access static member data.

That is what I understand now, so of course, It can be wrong or not enough. If you can contribute, please.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some answers :

1. If your media player is static, then it will be shared by all your instances of ServicePlayer. But read point 2 to understand more.
2. When you use new  you just create the service but it is a simple java object, not a service in the android meaning of the term : it is not started by the system, has no life cycle managed by the system, can't be bound, can't  be started and stopped properly. But there is no exception in Android : each new creates a new object. So there will be one instance of your service started properly by the program activity, and a second one only instanciated like a POJO.
3. I don't understand. Just bind to your service from your second activity as well.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but

1. Yes, media player is static but there are many variables that is not static also be accessed.

2. If its a new object, why it can stop music that played by old object of service player?

3. I mean, I just create a new object of service by the code (*) above, but I can access many members of it ( of course, not all) althougt it is not initialized. I know Java will automatically initialize primitive variabels but I see those variables still has value?

Sorry if my english upset you.

Comment: You can stop the music because you declared the mediaPlayer as being static so it is shared by all instances of the class. That's what static means. I don't know how your code is organized for other variables. Too many other java questions, please review the basics of Java programming about what static means and non static means and initialisations of data members.

Comment: Oh, I forget it, I will try it later.

Thank you so much.

Comment: And accept answers when they fit your needs. That's a good way to reward people helping you, and will make it more attractive to people to answer your future questions.